# How to prevent duplicate data being passed

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a web app that allows a user to select from a series of drugs that are stored in a table. However, at the moment I can add the same drug multiple times. How do I prevent this from happening? I am not sure how to stop this.

Here is my code.

```
<h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Medication Appropriateness Index</h1>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-12">
             <div class="well">
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="save_drug.php" method="post">
             <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Drug:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <select name="drug" id="Drug" class="form-control" required="">
                          <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select A drug...</option>
                          <?php
                          while($r1 = mysql_fetch_array($r_sel))
                          { ?>
                          <option value="<?php echo $r1['d_id']; ?>"><?php echo $r1['drug_name']; ?></option>
                          <?php
                          }
                         ?>
                          
                  </select>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Give it a unique constraint. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: probably want to start planning your transition away from mysql_* soon

Comment: could you show an example of that in my code please?

Comment: did you read the link chris85 provided?

Comment: why move from mysql?

Comment: Not mysql the db, `mysql_` the driver.

Comment: yes, but I am not sure how to adapt it

Comment: *"why move from mysql?"* - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: There are many threads and tutorials on how to switch over to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the advice

Comment: @chris85 yes the native drivers are way better performance and your right in saying that but still that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: to stick with the question in hand, you can use DISTINCT in SELECT and/or `GROUP BY col`

Comment: @JordanDavis my first comment answers how to avoid duplicates in the table.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you give me an example, I am very new to php and mysql

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT foo, col_x FROM table GROUP BY xxx` possibly with a `WHERE` clause - `WHERE col_x = 'xyz'` - some are optional here.

Comment: @BarryMcDaid1982 you do know you have blank <?php  tag at the bottom of the while statement

Comment: yeah I just seen that, I have been editing the code recently

Comment: @BarryMcDaid1982 Ok forsure, just making sure.

Comment: @chris85 I highly doubt that is the problem... possibly though...

Comment: @JordanDavis which, the driver or the unique?

Comment: @BarryMcDaid1982 my question to you is why are you generating a list like this, if it's a fixed list with set drugs why don't you just specify it in HTML... if you want it to be dynamic updated based on another value such as a category of drug why don't you use AJAX.

Comment: There are only 10 drugs in the table, it is only a prototype at the moment, so there are no categories, just  a list

Comment: Add `unique` and you are done. I'm on to the next thread.

Comment: @chris85 nah the unique the driver fine and I recommend but just unrelated. What I'm saying is why would anyone list duplicate values in the DB, if your pulling the values from the DB.... but really the question is why would you being doing that if the first place when you could pull then from a static JSON object or even specify it simply in HTML, read that comment I just posted above this.

Comment: @JordanDavis New products can always be added so it makes sense to use a DB instead of static values. The `unique` won't allow duplicates in the column so it should be used, that is what it is for.

Comment: @chris85 If thats what he is trying to accomplish sure but it doesn't make sense to allow a user to create imaginary drugs... there is a set list of around 1,500 drugs approved by the FDA . Why wouldn't you just pull in the list and all the associated info through in open-source API then use that as your list... Here is a link to a open-source drug database where you can pull all drug info --> http://www.drugbank.ca/documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```
ALTER TABLE  `table_name` ADD UNIQUE ( `column_that_should_be_unique` )
```

Or you can check it in PHP using :

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name='".$user_input."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    //block user from inserting data
}
```

Or you can do both to ensure that the database will have no duplicates

Comment: Second example opens OP to sql injections.

Comment: Thank you, can I ask how does that check to see if it is duplicated?

Comment: Would I insert the php line before or inside the while statement?

Comment: When you add a new drug, the query search your database to see how many drug with the name $user_input it has. If there is one or more then block the user from inserting a new drug. The best way is to prevent the user from ever inserting duplicate content when inserting new drugs instead of displaying only unique drugs.

Comment: Or you can do like that : array_unique($r1['drug_name']) to remove duplicates from your array. See : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Also use prepared statements don't use the SQL provided here. User input should never be inputted directly into SQL. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1